# Replacing the last line in Bash

Tags: bash

I have a shell script that's auto generated by a software and it looks something like:

```
#!/bin/sh

# The directory of this script is the expanded absolute path of the "$qt_prefix/bin" directory.
script_dir_path=`dirname $0`
script_dir_path=`(cd "$script_dir_path"; /bin/pwd)`

/home/akshay/Qt/6.2.4/gcc_64/bin/qmake -qtconf "$script_dir_path/target_qt.conf" $*
```

I want to replace the last line's first three separators to:

```
#!/bin/sh

# The directory of this script is the expanded absolute path of the "$qt_prefix/bin" directory.
script_dir_path=`dirname $0`
script_dir_path=`(cd "$script_dir_path"; /bin/pwd)`

/opt/qt/6.2.4/gcc_64/binqmake -qtconf "$script_dir_path/target_qt.conf" $*
```

I tried getting the last line by doing:

```
qmake_path=$(tail -n 1 $(find ${QT_ROOT}/android* -maxdepth 0 -type d | sort -r | head -1)/bin/qmake)
```

Then I used `read` to split it by space, I don't know how to get the first index, in this case the path. Any help on this is appreciated.

Comment: Doesn't the software have a way to configure the location of `qmake`, rather than forcing you to edit the script after it is generated?

Comment: I am putting this in a docker to build Android packages and the conan library is not available for Android builds yet. So not at the moment.

Comment: That's not a bash script, by the way. It's a sh script. See the first line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is just the short script you show, you can handle the change with `sed`, e.g.,

```bash
sed -i 's/^\/home\/akshay\/Qt/\/opt\/qt/' script.sh
```

Where `-i` will edit in-place and the normal substitution of `s/find/replace/` is used to locate a line beginning with `^\/home\/akshay\/Qt` (e.g. `"/home/akshaw/Qt"`) and replace as `\/opt\/qt` (e.g. `"/opt/qt"`)

**Example Use/Output**

Showing the result of the substitution output to `stdout` you would have:

```
$ sed 's/^\/home\/akshay\/Qt/\/opt\/qt/' script.sh
#!/bin/sh

# The directory of this script is the expanded absolute path of the "$qt_prefix/bin" directory.
script_dir_path=`dirname $0`
script_dir_path=`(cd "$script_dir_path"; /bin/pwd)`

/opt/qt/6.2.4/gcc_64/bin/qmake -qtconf "$script_dir_path/target_qt.conf" $*
```

**note:** you can also use alternate delimiters to avoid having to escape `'/'`, e.g.

```bash
sed 's#^/home/akshay/Qt#/opt/qt#' script.sh
```

That may be easier on the eyes.

**Replacing 3-Words Generically**

If the text of the first three words in `"/one/two/three/..."` can change and need to be replaced generically, you can simply use a character list to require *one-or-more* characters not `'/'` followed by `'/'` using `[^/]+/`, you can do:

```bash
sed -E -i 's#^/[^/]+/[^/]+/[^/]+/#/opt/qt/#' script.sh
```

The `-E` option is also used to specify "extended REGEX" syntax making the `'+'` (*one-or-more*) repetition character available.

With the change, it doesn't matter what the first 3-words are (so long as there is a `'/'` after the 3rd word, they will be replaced with `"/opt/qt/"`.

Comment: The thing with this is, I will have to know the user's name. Is it possible to just replace the first three words?

Comment: Yes, hold on and I"ll update.

Answer (score 1):

> Replacing the last line in Bash

I suspect that you're using the wrong tool (`tail`).

Try `head`:

```
head -n -1 <the file>
```

This will give you `<the file>` without the last line, which you can then replace with whatever you want in the output to the next step.

If what you want to replace it with is *based* on the previous last line:

```
last="$(tail -1 the_file)"

# manipulate $last here 

head -n -1 <the file>
echo "$the_manipulated_last"
```

Comment: Thanks for this. The problem is I don't know if `-qtconf "$script_dir_path/target_qt.conf" $*` will change in the future. So I want to keep that part there and just change the path

Comment: @Akshay Ok, I added something to deal with that.

Comment: Nice. Now how should I change the first three with `/opt/qt/`? Something with `sed`

Comment: The path can be different to each users, specifically the user name

Answer (score 1):

Use `ed` to **ed**it files:

```bash
ed -s script.sh <<'EOF'
$s!^/\([^/]*/\)\{3\}!/opt/qt/!
w
EOF
```

This will replace the first three parts of the path at the start of the last line of the file and save the change.

---

NetBSD `ed` and recent versions of GNU `ed` can use extended regular expressions to make it look a little nicer without the backslashes required by basic regular expressions:

```bash
ed -Es script.sh <<'EOF'
$s!^/([^/]*/){3}!/opt/qt/!
w
EOF
```